# Apache Nutch 1.11 installation on AIX machine giving bin/nutch: not found

Tags: apache, nutch

I am installing Apache nutch 1.11 binary distribution in an AIX machine. After unzipping the zip file "apache-nutch-1.11-bin.zip " under /usr directory. I just tried to run the bin/nutch command as per the instruction at https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

I am getting the following exception : bin/nutch: not found

I am using root user and have also tried running the "chmod +x bin/nutch" for permissions.

Can anyone help me in understanding what I am missing here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check the first line of that file: it it contains `#!/bin/bash` then you have to have a file/symlink `/bin/bash`. (Alt this point, I think you should ask your sys-admin for help.)

Comment: I checked with my sys-admin and he resolved it by renaming the "nutch" script to nutch.ksh and changing the first line in nutch script from "#!/bin/bash" to "#!/bin/ksh". Now, when I run the command as "bin/nutch.ksh" it works.I am not sure though if it is a right solution but it is working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, after unzipping the zip file, you did changed the directory to  "apache-nutch-1.11" in your command prompt and then entered the bin/nutch command. right? 
if you did please look for a "bin" subdirectory in "apache-nutch-1.11" directory. If there isn't any, I guess the zip file you downloaded has a problem. If there is, in your command prompt first change the directory to where it is in, and then run the command. I hope it helps.